# Error when launching Google Maps Activity

Tags: android

i want to make an adroid app with multiple activities, one of them is a google map activity that i want to make it to get your location and show custom nearby places as car gas stations, etc(also if you can show me how to make this please), and whenever i am launching this activity, the app crashes due to this error(i want to mentioned that i searched on the internet and here for an answer but not found anything):

```
03-24 14:22:24.737 12970-12970/com.mihai_bucur.happycar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.mihai_bucur.happycar, PID: 12970
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mihai_bucur.happycar/com.mihai_bucur.happycar.GooglePlacesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.mihai_bucur.happycar.GooglePlacesActivity.onCreate(GooglePlacesActivity.java:65)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

And this is the activity code :

```
package com.mihai_bucur.happycar;

/**
* Created by Mihai on 18.12.2016.
*/

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class GooglePlacesActivity extends      android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyDCS0BtucuGB4nDRV15NYbT6fqLHtWgtQs";
GoogleMap googleMap;
EditText placeText;
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if (!checkPlayServices()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_places);

    placeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.placeText);
    Button btnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
//        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)    getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 //        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
//        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

    btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String type = placeText.getText().toString();
            StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + type);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);

            GooglePlacesReadTask googlePlacesReadTask = new GooglePlacesReadTask();
            Object[] toPass = new Object[2];
            toPass[0] = googleMap;
            toPass[1] = googlePlacesUrl.toString();
            googlePlacesReadTask.execute(toPass);
        }
    });
}



public boolean checkPlayServices() {
    final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
```

}

And thi is the AndroidManifes.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mihai_bucur.happycar">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!--Pentru a vedea daca telefonul e conectat la vreo retea, folosim -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- Daca suntem sau nu conectati la net -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!-- Pentru a determina locatia aproximativa cu wifi sau date mobile -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<!-- Pnt -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



<application
    android:name=".RemindMe"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/camaro_laucher"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Meniu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_meniu"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Setari" />
    <activity android:name=".Documente" />
    <activity android:name=".AddAlarmActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".GooglePlacesActivity"/>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmSetter">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />

    <service android:name=".AlarmService" />

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

</application>
```

Hope you can help me :D

UPDATE :

```
03-24 15:00:49.576 4339-4339/com.mihai_bucur.happycar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.mihai_bucur.happycar, PID: 4339
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mihai_bucur.happycar/com.mihai_bucur.happycar.GooglePlacesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.mihai_bucur.happycar.GooglePlacesActivity.onLocationChanged(GooglePlacesActivity.java:143)
                                                                        at com.mihai_bucur.happycar.GooglePlacesActivity.onCreate(GooglePlacesActivity.java:71)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                        at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
03-24 15:00:50.367 4339-4346/com.mihai_bucur.happycar W/art: Suspending all threads took: 130.004ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` in `onMapReady()`

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Also in your `onLocationChanged()` modify code to this:

```
    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    if(googleMap != null){
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
    }
}
```

Basic idea is GoogleMap `onMapReady()` will be called when the Map object is properly initialized. Until that time your map object will be null. So it is best to do your Map related operation in `onMapReady()` function.

Comment: Thanks man, It worked first time  :)),but  now it gives another error  i will add it on main question

Comment: Thanks man, now it works, and now I will figure out how to show me nearby places that I define, I will come back with questions when I get stuck, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hello, @rafsanahmad007 i got stuck again, i have found a tutorial to make an activity to show me POI, but whn i run it it gets me this error: 

      **_java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void         com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(co      m.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null   object reference_**  

because of this line:

`((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMapAsync(this);`